# Trailing characters in Rust when trying to serialize API response

Tags: rust

I'm trying to wrap an API using rust, so long no problems but one endpoint is giving me a big pain in the head.

the endpoint returns a valid JSON as the other endpoints from this API.

The problem is when I try to work with the response I get the following error:

```
error decoding response body: trailing characters at line 1 column 146
```

Get function:

```
pub fn get<T: DeserializeOwned>(&self, endpoint: API, request: Option<String>) -> Result<T> {
    let mut url: String = format!("{}{}", self.host, String::from(endpoint));
    if let Some(request) = request {
        if !request.is_empty() {
            url.push_str(format!("?{}", request).as_str());
        }
    }

    let client = &self.inner_client;
    let response = client.get(url.as_str()).send()?;

    self.handler(response)
}
```

Handler function:

```
fn handler<T: DeserializeOwned>(&self, response: Response) -> Result<T> {
    match response.status() {
        StatusCode::OK => {
            let l = response.json::<T>()?;
            Ok(l)
        },
        s => {
            bail!(format!("Received response: {:?}", s));
        }
    }
}
```

Enpoint funcion:

```
pub fn get_depth<S>(&self, symbol: S) -> Result<OrderBook>
    where
        S: Into<String>,
{
    let mut parameters: BTreeMap<String, String> = BTreeMap::new();
    parameters.insert("symbol".into(), symbol.into());
    let request = build_request(parameters);
    self.client.get(API::Spot(Spot::Depth), Some(request))
}
```

Models:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct OrderBook {
    pub last_update_id: u64,
    pub asks: Vec<Asks>,
    pub bids: Vec<Bids>,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Bids {
    #[serde(with = "string_or_float")]
    pub price: f64,
    #[serde(with = "string_or_float")]
    pub qty: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Asks {
    #[serde(with = "string_or_float")]
    pub price: f64,
    #[serde(with = "string_or_float")]
    pub qty: f64,
}
```

API response:

```
{
  "lastUpdateId": 1595750078,
  "bids": [
    [
      "0.00001661",
      "24250.00000000",
      []
    ],
    [
      "0.00001660",
      "65159.00000000",
      []
    ]
  ],
  "asks": [
    [
      "0.00001662",
      "26397.00000000",
      []
    ],
    [
      "0.00001663",
      "54421.00000000",
      []
    ]
  ]
}
```

I was testing this mocking the API response and removing the empty arrays from `asks` and `bids` and it worked flawless. I don't know why the `[]` is a problem and I can figure out how to solve this problem. So really I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you put together a minimal reproducible example on [the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)?

Comment: @MTCoster yes, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=fc0b627521e4a4cfc8f494eb8177ac62, is working in local but playground fails at send the request to mockapi,`asks` works, `bids` cause the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem boils down to matching your rust `struct` with the response structure. I'm using the example with `String` from your playground link.

#### Response

```
{
   "lastUpdateId":1595750078,
   "bids":[
      [
         "0.00001661",
         "24250.00000000",
         [
            
         ]
      ],
      [
         "0.00001660",
         "65159.00000000",
         [
            
         ]
      ]
   ],
   "asks":[
      [
         "0.00001662",
         "26397.00000000"
      ],
      [
         "0.00001663",
         "54421.00000000"
      ]
   ]
}
```

#### Your Structs

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct OrderBook {
    pub last_update_id: u64,
    pub asks: Vec<Asks>,
    pub bids: Vec<Bids>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Bids {
    pub price: String,
    pub qty: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Asks {
    pub price: String,
    pub qty: String,
}
```

Now if you look at the `bids` json, the empty array is not represented in the `Bids` structure in your code. Hence calling `serde_json::from_str::<OrderBook>(json)` fails, as it's encountering a new array where nothing is expected anymore.

#### Solution

Introduce a new (optional) field in `Bids`, representing the array. I cannot say which structure this would be, as your example only shows the empty representation. `pub x: Vec<()>` would also work, though I'm certain the API might sent real data if available.

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Bids {
    pub price: String,
    pub qty: String,
    pub something_else: Vec<()>, // or Vec<AnotherStruct>
}
```

Comment: Yes I figure out the same, I was just hopping a way to ignore that empty value (it's always empty, the API says "ignore this" in the docs).

Comment: @exsnake I don't think you can, unless you implement a custom deserialization. https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/540 discusses `it would make since for us to simply ignore the extra digits`. Not sure it will come anytime though